# Matlab rgb2hsv changes image

Tags: image, matlab, rgb, hsv

I am trying to convert an array of RGB values into an array of HSV values in Matlab. I am running the following code:

```
pic = imread('ColoradoMountains.jpg');

pic = rgb2hsv(pic);

imwrite(pic,'pic.jpg')
```

But the image that gets written has completely different colors. I've been trying to set the color map to hsv, but I'm not sure if that even makes sense. Nothing on the internet comes up with my keywords, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: jpeg does not support hsv or rgb, jpeg is always YCbCr

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the colormap that imwrite is supposed to use. Try this:

```
imwrite(pic,colormap('HSV'),'pic.png');
```

Here's the documentation for imwrite: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html

Comment: Does this work? According to the documentation, I would expect `pic` to be an HSV-Indexed n*m*1 image, not an native n*m*3 hsv image. I did not manage to write it correctly.

Comment: This causes me to get "error: feval: function 'HSV' not found". Maybe it's easier to just write back to rgb?

Comment: @Daniel, Right, I wrote it to file as a png instinctively. I'll look into how to do it to jpg shortly.

Comment: @user3761002, that's kind of strange... the fact that it's evoking feval means it's interpreting 'HSV' as a function, which it shouldn't be doing. Are you sure typed it the way I did it in my answer?

Comment: There are multiple issues with this answer. 1) It's colormap(hsv), not colormap('hsv') at least if I take a look at the documentation. 2) colormaps are for indexed images (see my answer), rgb2hsv does not output an indexed image.

Comment: @Daniel both colormap('HSV') and colormap(hsv) return the same value. Try it and you will see that.

rgb2hsv returns a matrix with the exact same dimensions that as the passed matrix.

The one issue that the asker might have would be writing to file which is something that I didn't address. You can't write an n*m*3 matrix to a jpg file.

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab you have to distinguish between an indexed image and an 3-channel image. An indexed image is a n*m*1 image where each value of the [0,1] range is associated to a colour. This association is called colour map, which could be for example a unit circle in HSV or RGB. This can be written using `imwrite` with the map parameter, but this is not what you want.

What you obviously want is an HSV-encoded image, which means the three rgb-channels are converted to three hsv channels. This is (as far as I know) not possible. If you take a look into the documentation of `imwrite`, you can see how CMYK-Encoded images are written, this is done implicit passing a n*m*4 image. Is there any of the standard file formats which supports HSV? If so I'll take a closer look at this format.